# Extracting one specific data from a JSon file then sum all of them up

Tags: java, json, rest

So I'm kind of stuck. I'm experiencing with JSon and I'm trying to get all the total_price of different orders from a JSON file. I can read the file, but I'm having issue getting that specific information then sum it all up.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {




        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                    "/orders.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;


            JSONArray orderList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("orders");

            System.out.println("\norders");
            Iterator<String> iterator = orderList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
            obj = parser.parse(sCurrentLine);
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
    for(obj : jsonArray){
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
        JSONObject realTitle = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("0");
        String name = (String) realTitle.get("title");
    }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

For the JSON file:

```
{
"orders":[
{
"id":4251070723,
"email":"heathcote_amya@gmail.com",
"closed_at":null,
"created_at":"2016-12-05T23:16:40-05:00",
"updated_at":"2016-12-05T23:16:40-05:00",
"number":137,
"note":null,
"token":"c460f260f4f38b8a2b1f78e6efd0140e",
"gateway":"",
"test":false,
"total_price":"179.04",
"default":true
},
{
"id":4251070787,
"email":"napoleon.batz@gmail.com",
"closed_at":null,
"created_at":"2016-12-05T23:16:40-05:00",
"updated_at":"2016-12-05T23:16:41-05:00",
"number":138,
"note":null,
"token":"54c4f1735cfec8f98ad16ae5e9a161cd",
"gateway":"",
"test":false,
"total_price":"14.62"
}
]
}
```

The error I get is for(obj : jsonArray) is causing me issue, but honestly, I don't think I'm even on the right path.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: If you get an error, then post the complete and exact eror. "is causing me issue" doesn't tell us anything. And please post code that compiles. What is `sCurrentLine`? If you have a single file to parse, why do you call parse() several times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has obvious compile time errors. With in the for loop, you are again trying to do a get(0), which is incorrect.

I have refined the code.

Try this. Its giving proper result as below

> The price data of each order --{4251070723=179.04, 4251070787=14.62}.
>
> The total Price of all order --193.66

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Map<String, String> priceData = new HashMap<>();
        BigDecimal totalPrice = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        String orderId = null;
        String orderPrice = null;

        try {
            String sCurrentLine = null;

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                    "orders.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray orderList = (JSONArray)(jsonObject.get("orders"));
            System.out.println("Complete order list --"+orderList.toString());

            for(Object singleOrder : orderList) {
                JSONObject singleArrayData = (JSONObject) singleOrder;
                orderId = singleArrayData.get("id").toString();
                orderPrice = singleArrayData.get("total_price").toString();
                priceData.put(orderId, orderPrice);
                totalPrice = totalPrice.add(new BigDecimal(orderPrice));
            }
            System.out.println("The price data of each order --"+priceData.toString());
            System.out.println("The total Price of all order --"+totalPrice);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```